# Create a relationship between domain model and SimpleMembership model using EF6 and MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a FK relationship between classes in my domain model, which is a separate but referenced project, and the SimpleMembership model. I want the FK in the domain model so each UserProfile record can have many records in my domain model, but since I don't have a reference to the UserProfile class in my domain model I don't know how I can?

Is this possible without putting my domain model into my MVC project directly?

or

How do I move the membership scaffolding from my MVC project into my domain project? I tried adding a reference of my MVC project to my Domain model but I got a compile time warning complaining about circular references.

Any help welcomed.

Jason.

Comment: you can add new property to compare with unique username each users and then operate by this key in linq queries like Join

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SimpleMembership because it gives absolutely nothing, adds dependencies on WebMatrix assembly, and brings complexity to the code.

I recommend to get rid of SimpleMembership until it's too late and add PasswordHash field right to your user entity.

To authenticate the user with forms authentication you can use the following code:

```
if(validateUser(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password)) // your own function
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(viewModel.Email, true);
    // redirect the user
}
```

In this case you can always access user's email by `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`